# Is there any well maintained and timely updated compass/sass bootstrap project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

Is there any well maintained and timely updated compass/sass bootstrap project.

I know a couple of projects on githib but 1) it's very difficult to find the original repo in the jungle of forks and 2) most repos are old and not tracking the latest Bootstrap versions.

Therefore, I turn to you - Oh mighty and wise stackoverflow community.

Comment: I simply prefer SASS/Compass to Less.

Comment: I'm not asking why you want one in Sass, but why would you want one at all.

Comment: I know I can  do everything with plain old css but I just prefer sass to plain css syntax. Not to mention mixins, variables, color functions and calculations features that make it very easy to express a lot with much less typing.

Comment: I know all about the benefits of Sass.  My opinion is that Twitter Bootstrap is a waste of space and I can't fathom why anyone would want it at all.

Comment: Assuming by "space" you mean bandwith, you can really it trim down a lot by only importing the stuff you need. 
In any serious design work, you will be creating almost the equal amount of css

Answer (score 2):

The most popular options appear to be:

- https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass - last updated 1 day ago
- https://github.com/vwall/compass-twitter-bootstrap - last updated 1 month ago

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300450/1684247)

Comment: I am using compass-twitter-bootstrap right now but it's at a bootstrap 2.0 while 2.2 is almost out.
Did not know bootstrap-sass but will check it out.

Comment: Looks like the [Compass support](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#compass) is a new addition since 2.0, and that repo seems to be actively maintained.

Answer (score 2):

As Sara pointed out, [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) is the more active of the two and its v2.1.0.0 seems to match the latest Bootstrap release quite well – I've been using it in production for a few days now without noticing any serious porting issues, and the few there are [are taken care of](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/commit/2a7c21d40692b512c02deb730fe8caefe1e474da).
Overwriting Bootstrap's default variables by using their SASS-versions worked flawless as well as using some of Bootstrap's mixins, though I haven't began [working on the grid yet](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html).

Tracking back,

- Bootstrap 2.1 was released [August 20, 2012](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Changelog) …
- bootstrap-sass master [updated ~two weeks later](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/commit/bc406b198148d8d2a4b56b7cd6592df60b961556) …
- the updated gem was [released the same day](http://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions/2.1.0.0)

– so I'm under the impression that the project does its best to keep up-to-date with Bootstrap itself. I haven't had to make the decision for bootstrap-sass myself – it was already decided before I came into the project.

"[Twitter Bootstrap, Less, and Sass: Understanding Your Options for Rails 3.1](http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/)", a very informative article on the topic looking in detail at

- [less-rails-bootstrap](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap)
- [sass-twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap)
- [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass)
- [bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails)

mentions another gem worth looking at: [bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails), which also makes use of SASS and matches Twitter Bootstrap v2.1.1 – seems its [release-dates even beat the previously mentioned](http://rubygems.org/gems/anjlab-bootstrap-rails).